# Is there anyway to make a div blur or focus?

Tags: javascript, html

If i give a div a focus/blur event handler, when will the handler (if ever)  run?

Answer (score 12):

If you give the `div` a `tabindex` attribute, it will be able to accept focus:

```
<div id="example" tabindex="0">Random content</div>
```

You can then attach `focus` and `blur` event handlers as you normally would. For example:

```
document.getElementById("example").onfocus = function() {
    console.log("focused");
}
```

Focus will be given to the `div` when you click on it, and `blur` will trigger when you click on any other element.

Answer (score 2):

If you give a div element a tabindex attribute, then it will be focusable (in browsers that support that part of the HTML 5 draft). Theoretically it will then fire focus and blur events.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't do that though.

Comment: but i can't solve this problem without this hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745059/implementation-details-of-date-picker-at-http-jqueryui-com-demos-datepicker

Comment: Yes you can. Set a variable when any element in the calendar or the input gains the focus. Unset it when any of them lose the focus. Close the calendar only after a second has passed and then only if the variable isn't set. I'd avoid the problem by triggering the calendar only if a button is activated; being forced to use a GUI to pick a date is annoying when I can just type it.