# checkExternalClick is doing the opposite of what I want it to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I previously asked a question as to how to make a box close when the user clicks anywhere outside of it, after trying the background overlay as given in [this questions's answer by Jason Striegel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745059/how-do-we-make-it-such-that-when-the-user-clicks-on-anywhere-but-the-popup-box). But it was not working and not much attention was received. I'm now attempting to approach the problem from the other answer, given by Aaron Ray. He suggested the 
checkExternalClick. I've set it up, but now the box closes whenever I click anywhere *inside* the box, not anywhere outside!

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initHUDWindow();
});

function initHUDWindow()
{
    $(document).mousedown(checkExternalClick);  
}

function checkExternalClick(event)
{
   var target = $(event.target);
   if(target[0].id != "box")
   {        
      hideBox();
   }
}

function hideBox()
{
   $(".BoxContainer").hide();
}
```

CSS:

```
.Box
{
position:absolute;
top:15%;
left:15%;
width:500px;
height:600px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:2;
}


.BoxContainer
{
background-image:url('images/box.png');
z-index:2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "box">
   <div class = "Box BoxContainer"></div> 
</div>
```

As I said, this will close the box when the user clicks inside the box. But wait! I thought it was supposed to close the box if they clicked outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initHUDWindow();

    $("#box").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});

function initHUDWindow()
{
    $(document).click(checkExternalClick);  
}

function checkExternalClick(event)
{
   hideBox();
}

function hideBox()
{
   $(".BoxContainer").hide();
}
```

Comment: For the record, while my answer fixes the posted approach, this is generally the way I prefer.  Although I see no reason to check if the box is already visible.

Comment: @kingjiv - Why to find the container and hide if its already hidden?

Comment: If it's more efficient to check first, I would expect jquery would add the check within `hide` (and maybe already have).  It may be just as time consuming to check if it's hidden as it is to just call `hide`.  And in reality since the time it takes is negligible, the code is cleaner without the check.  Doesn't hurt though.

Comment: I agree. but to call hide you still have to find $(".BoxContainer"). Anyways the time is negligible as compared to the clean code :)

Comment: This solution ceased all box hiding when clicking anywhere. Sorry!

Comment: @Briz - What do you mean by all box? It will hide all the boxes which have class "BoxContainer". If you dont want this then change the selector as per your need. But let me tell you this is the best solution to acheive this type of functionality on the page.

Comment: I do agree that it may be the best functionality, as even the other answerer said so, however, in my situation, your code does not work. I mean by my previous statement that when I try your code, when I click outside the box, it doesn't hide. When I click in the box, it doesn't hide.

Comment: @Briz - Please try now, I have edited my answer, it should work now as  you needed.

Comment: The problem was, you were using mousedown event to hide the container :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best approach overall, but the issue here is that elements within the element do not have that ID.  I think this will fix it though (untested):

```
function checkExternalClick(event)
{
   var target = $(event.target);
   if(target[0].id != "box" && target.closest("#box").length === 0)
   {        
      hideBox();
   }
}
```

This should check that you haven't clicked on the element or any element within it.

Comment: I do not have a #box element specifically defined in my CSS. The only place is use it is in the HTML, when I put the box div id around the two classes Box and BoxContainer. I don't know if you saw that or not. I found that the box will close if you click within a certain other region which contains a separate element (and still if within the box) but this answer at least didn't break the functionality

Comment: I'm not sure why css would be involved here.  The javascript can access an element regardless of if there is css defined for it.

Comment: I'm not sure either, I'm certainly not an expert or else I wouldn't need to ask about silly things like this. I think the problem is actually something to do with how my program is grabbing screens. It's a large game that I'm doing under a company so there's a lot more to this than the box. With your answer I was able to figure this out, so I view your answer as the most helpful.